# What does it mean by “pinch a hole in one thing or another”?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

https://youtu.be/9C20XmtHkQM?t=583

> (9:45) “I’m not pinching a hole in one thing or another”

At least that’s what I hear, but I have no idea what it means. I know what “pinch” and “hole” is but can’t figure out the meaning of the whole sentence she said.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Your link is only to youtube, not a particular video: perhaps you could update it.  I'll guess it's "**Punch** a hole", a common idiom for "**make** a hole" which can be used both literally (hole through a wall) or figuratively (trying to criticise something).

Comment: @jonathanjo Sorry I added the link. So, does the phrase mean what you explained in that context?

Comment: Based on context she seems to be using it to mean that she's not being tied down/confined to one thing or another, but is instead able to study a wide range of subjects. It's not a saying I'm familiar with, though. If I had to guess at an etymology, "punching a hole" in a voting card ties you down to one candidate - by not punching a hole, you leave your options open. And that somehow changed from punching to pinching.